# Is it possible to dynamically add embedded code blocks to asp.net page similar to how controls are added dynamically from code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dynamic

One can dynamically add controls to an asp.net page.

```
    Label myLabel = new Label();
    myLabel.Text = "Sample Label";
    Panel1.Controls.Add(myLabel);
```

I want to know if it is possible to add embedded code blocks dynamically?

If I do something like the code below, the embedded code will be **rendered literally**.

```
    // Use <%#Page.Title%> or <%=Page.Title%> for example
    LiteralControl literal = new LiteralControl("<%=Page.Title%>"); 
    Panel1.Controls.Add(literal);
```

The output of the above code will be

`<%=Page.Title%>`

Is there a way to make ASP.NET evaluate the embedded code blocks that are added dynamically?

Comment: Why would you need them. You have code behind file to handel this and write your logic.

Comment: @Guanxi In a certain situation I do need them. I can't know beforehand what the actual code block will be. My question is not whether I really need them or not. My question is '**is it possible**'?

Comment: It's Possible, But Meaningless.

Comment: @Eugene Meaning is up to me to derive. If you know it is possible then please let me know how. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
LiteralControl literalContols = new LiteralControl();
literalContols.Text = Page.Title; 
this.MasterForm.Controls.Add(literalContols);
```

[image]